# How to perform a Click in C# in stead of Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#

For a project on school I have to make an application which can fill in a form from a second hand selling page.
This is the page :
http://www.2dehands.be/plaats/

My problem : 
If I execute javascript like this :

```
document.getElementById("level1-option").selectedIndex = "1";
```

it does select the right index.

But it seems like the site asks a real 'click' event.
How do I do that.

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/1521-How-call-Postback-from-Javascript.aspx

Do let me know if doesn't works

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
document.getElementById("level1-option").fireEvent("onchange");
```

or

```
// Create a new 'change' event
var event = new Event('change');

// Trigger it.
element.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Triggering events manualy